# AWS DynamoDB separate environment (dev / prod)

Tags: react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, environment

I am building a app using react-native and AWS Amplify and about to release.
Before that, I want to separate my dev/prod environments. I am using AWS Amplify, DynamoDB, S3, Lamda functions, SNS(Notification), Cognito(Auth) so on... I want to separate at least DynamoDB.

I have experience in Java/Oracle based development. In this case, I controlled whether to connect to dev db, pro db through env file, and I want to separate it in this way in the react-native, Amplify environment.

This is my first time developing it with react-native and Amplify. I searched Google and couldn't find the answer I wanted.

If you know how, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As DynamoDB is a managed/serverless service, its not typical to have a dev/prod environment for the table alone as there is no patching or database upgrades required. Usually you would have 2 AWS accounts, one for Dev, the other for Prod (keeping them isolated).

With that said, to suit your specific needs, as the highest level of construct in DynamoDB is the `Table`, then you simply require two tables. Instead of pointing to `dev` or `prod` you simply change the name of the table you point to:

1. MyTable-Prod
2. MyTable-Dev

Then you can still resolve the table in your env file, or you can use parameter store to resolve the table name based on `prod` or `dev` keys:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html